# $(...).perfectScrollbar is not a function error when building JS with webpack

Tags: javascript, jquery, perfect-scrollbar

I am working with `Laravel 5.6` and building my `app.js` with `webpack`.

I installed with `npm` [perfect-scrollbar](https://travis-ci.org/utatti/perfect-scrollbar.svg?branch=master) but I cannot get it to work. When I load the page I get:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).perfectScrollbar is not a function
```

My js bootstrap is:

```
try {

    window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');
    require('popper.js/dist/umd/popper');
    require('./bootstrap/bootstrap.bundle');

} catch (e) {
}

import PerfectScrollbar from 'perfect-scrollbar';
```

I have also tried:

```
const PerfectScrollbar = require('perfect-scrollbar');
window.PerfectScrollbar = require('perfect-scrollbar');
```

I initialise the scroll bar like this:

```
$('.sidebar .sidebar-wrapper, .main-panel').perfectScrollbar();
```

If I load the `perfect-scrollbar` code via CDN after my `app.js` then my code works.

How do I correctly import `perfect-scrollbar` and make it available to the global scope of the code?

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue. The fix is to expose jquery globally **via webpack** (either as an external, or via the expose plugin).